# While loop is not repeating in Java

Tags: java, while-loop

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        System.out.print("Want to play? ('Y' or 'N'): ");
        String want = input.nextLine();

        double money;
        String word1 = "", word2 = "", word3 = "";
        int randInt1, randInt2, randInt3;

        double totalMoney = 0.0, totalEarnings = 0.0;

        do
        {
            System.out.print("How much money do you want to enter? $");
            money = input.nextDouble();
            totalMoney += money;

            randInt1 = rand.nextInt(6);

            if (randInt1 == 0)
            {
                word1 = "Cherries";
            }
            else if (randInt1 == 1)
            {
                word1 = "Oranges";
            }
            else if (randInt1 == 2)
            {
                word1 = "Plums";
            }
            else if (randInt1 == 3)
            {
                word1 = "Bells";
            }
            else if (randInt1 == 4)
            {
                word1 = "Melons";
            }
            else
            {
                word1 = "Bars";
            }

            randInt2 = rand.nextInt(6);

            if (randInt2 == 0)
            {
                word2 = "Cherries";
            }
            else if (randInt2 == 1)
            {
                word2 = "Oranges";
            }
            else if (randInt2 == 2)
            {
                word2 = "Plums";
            }
            else if (randInt2 == 3)
            {
                word2 = "Bells";
            }
            else if (randInt2 == 4)
            {
                word2 = "Melons";
            }
            else
            {
                word2 = "Bars";
            }

            randInt3 = rand.nextInt(6);

            if (randInt3 == 0)
            {
                word3 = "Cherries";
            }
            else if (randInt3 == 1)
            {
                word3 = "Oranges";
            }
            else if (randInt3 == 2)
            {
                word3 = "Plums";
            }
            else if (randInt3 == 3)
            {
                word3 = "Bells";
            }
            else if (randInt3 == 4)
            {
                word3 = "Melons";
            }
            else
            {
                word3 = "Bars";
            }

            System.out.println(word1 + "  " + word2 + "  " + word3);

            if (word1.equals(word2) && word1.equals(word3))
            {
                System.out.printf("You won $%.2f\n", (money * 3));
                totalEarnings += (money * 3);
            }
            else if ((word1.equals(word2) && !word1.equals(word3)) || (!word1.equals(word2) && word1.equals(word3)))
            {
                System.out.printf("You won $%.2f\n", (money * 2));
                totalEarnings += (money * 2);
            }
            else if ((word2.equals(word1) && !word2.equals(word3)) || (!word2.equals(word1) && word2.equals(word3)))
            {
                System.out.printf("You won $%.2f\n", (money * 2));
                totalEarnings += (money * 2);
            }
            else if ((word2.equals(word1) && !word2.equals(word3)) || (!word2.equals(word1) && word2.equals(word3)))
            {
                System.out.printf("You won $%.2f\n", (money * 2));
                totalEarnings += (money * 2);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You won $0");
            }

            System.out.print("\nWant to play again? ('Y' or 'N'): ");
            want = input.nextLine();
        }
        while (want.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

        System.out.printf("\n\nYou entered a total of $%.2f into the slot machine.\n", totalMoney);
        System.out.printf("Your total earnings are $%.2f", totalEarnings);
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble trying to get this while loop to repeat.
I included the sentinel value of user input "Y" or "N" ("N" for stop).
In the while loop, it asks user to enter the sentinel again. But this part is not executing when I run the program.

In the console, the last lines shown are:

Want to play again? ('Y' or 'N'):

You entered a total of $15.00 into the slot machine.

Your total earnings are $0.00

So the last input for "Y" or "N" is not executing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: Just an observation, your code would be cleaner with swtiches rather than if and else if's (https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_switch.asp)

Comment: Why dont you print the value of want before the end of the loop?

Comment: @NomadMaker why would I need to print the value of "want"? That variable just contains whether the user wants to carry on playing.

Comment: Because it obviously doesn't contain what you think it does, and printing such things is one way of debugging.

Comment: @NomadMaker I see, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not consuming the "Enter" with your code

```
    money = input.nextDouble();
```

Then when you get to your code

```
    want = input.nextLine();
```

an empty string is returned.

Place the following code after your code for `input.nextDouble()`

```
        input.nextLine();
```

This will consume the "Enter" from when you asked for the bet amount.